# SPLIT_PART function used in a select statement in Snowflake Stored procedure returns null value

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

SPLIT_PART function used in a select statement in Snowflake Stored procedure returns null value.

```
var stmt5 = snowflake.CreateStatement({sqltext:`Select SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(:1,''/'',2),''.gz'',1)`,binds:[stagename]});
var queryText=stmt5.getSqlText();
var x=stmt5.execute();
x.next();
```

stagename is retrieved from the List @my_stage command result and  the result of the Split Part is used in the Copy Command for inserting records into a snowflake table.

If somebody responds will share the code thru an email to help me fix the issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're using JavaScript with backticks, so there's no need to escape the single quotes. By doing so, it actually looks like an empty string. This is how it would look in your SQL history tab:

```
Select SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(:1,''/'',2),''.gz'',1)
```

If you put a file name in and try that:

```
Select SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART('mypath/myfile.gz',''/'',2),''.gz'',1)
```

This doesn't actually return a null value. It's a syntax error, so maybe this execute call is in a try/catch block. That would return a null value when you try to use .next(),

Try it with the quotes single:

```
var stmt5 = snowflake.CreateStatement({sqltext:`Select SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(:1,'/',2),'.gz',1)`,binds:[stagename]});
```

Comment: I tried this as per the suggestion above:
snowflake.createStatement({sqltext:`Select SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(:1,'/',2),'.gz',1) as name`,binds:[stagename]});
I still get the below error: SQL Error [1003] [42000]: SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 22 at position 87 unexpected '/'.

Comment: I tried the solution with single quote as below:
SELECT split_part(split_part('@my_int_stage/Torani_190212_190311.csv.gz','/',2),'.gz',1) This works but snowflake.createStatement({sqltext:`Select SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(:1,'/',2),'.gz',1) as name`,binds:[stagename]}); I get the below error:
SQL Error [1003] [42000]: SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 22 at position 87 unexpected '/'.

Comment: The second code example does not have a single quote that starts the select statement. Is that a typo?

Comment: I didn't include the single quote for the start and end of the select statement.
I was told to use it like below still my query brings null value 
`select split_part(split_part(:1,\'/\',2),\'.gz\',1) as name`,binds:[stagename]}